# Altering a form to set it's target to _parent

Tags: forms

I have a form in an iframe, when the form gets submitted I need the target to be _parent.

How do we add `target="_parent"` to a form element in drupal 7. I am pretty sure hook_form_alter is the best way to go just not sure about what var gets edited and how.

-thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$form['#attributes']['target'] = '_parent'`. If the form is implemented from another module, you can use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), or [hook_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to add that attribute.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the form ID for the form you need to target') {
    $form['#attributes']['target'] = '_parent';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to change your form you can use hook_form_alter
example

```
function login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id=="user_login_block")
    {
         $items[] = '<a id="fpassword" target="_parent" title ="'.t('Request new password via e-mail.').'" href="#">'.t('Request new password').'<a>';
         $form['links'] = array('#markup' => theme('item_list', array('items' => $items))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: edited question to ask HOW we do it with hook_form_alter

Comment: If you want something like that I edit my answer

Comment: Hi ahmed, close but, i need to add target="_parent" to the actual <form> element, not to an object in the form.

Comment: @ChrisBorgia `$form['#attributes']['target'] = '_parent';` should do the trick

Comment: i think u can use this $form['#attributes'] = array('target' => '_parent');

Comment: Thank you @Clive, and thank you Ahmed, `$form['#attributes']['target'] = '_parent';` did the trick