# Drupal.attachBehaviors only working for some fields when using Ajax .load

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, ajax

The following code works for some things that I do in terms of .load() such as adding Chosen to fields.
But it won't do anything to date fields, conditional fields or field groups. They get left with no JS.

I've added other similar forms on the page as a test so the scripts are available and I've also added the scripts to the theme's .info file.

Is there any way to fully .load() a form? It has to added using Ajax as it's a really slow form and kills website performance.

EDIT: As Jimmy Ko pointed out, this isn't a good method. Instead, [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28491/altering-a-form-to-set-its-target-to-parent) shows how to change the target of a form submit in an iFrame to the parent so I'll try loading the form that way with a custom tpl so only the form is shown in the iFrame.

```
   (function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Check so it doesn't repeat load
    if ($('#page-content-st-node-form').length == 0) {
    // Load 
     $('.page-bar').load('/node/add/page-content-st #page-content-st-node-form', {}, function() {
     Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#page-content-st-node-form'));
     });

    }

  }
};
}

)(jQuery);
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect .load() to be much faster, honestly. What makes that form slow to load?

Comment: Not sure.. Just a lot of fields I guess (around 25) so it makes the page load time up from 1.5 seconds to 3.5 seconds. I need the form hidden and ready to be opened in a modal on every page so I'm happy to use Ajax to do it and only show the +Add button when it's done.

Comment: This is not a good way. `jQuery.load` can only update the HTML but most interactive widget requires additional JS library and even `Drupal.settings` values to work. Chosen is working just because chosen library is loaded and it does not depends on the value of `Drupal.settings`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm realising this isn't going to work.. Going to go with an iFrame instead I think and change the target.

Comment: I am going to provide an answer with an approach I have used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

$.load() will not update the Drupal.settings object, which contains the references to which fields need to be ajaxified. This is why you are seeing the issue you have. In order to load a form through AJAX, you need to return the form as well as the settings for the form alonng with the form, after the form has been rendered. This will update the Drupal.settings object, which then will ajaxify your form.

First you need to declare a callback path in hook_menu()

```
function hook_menu()
{
  $menu['my/ajax/callback'] = array
  (
    'title' => 'AJAX callback',
    'page callback' => 'my_ajax_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $menu;
}
```

Then you need to generate your form, and ajax settings, in the callback path

```
function my_ajax_callback()
{
  $form = drupal_get_form('some_form');
  $rendered_form = render($form);
  $javascript = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL);
  $settings = FALSE;
  if(isset($javascript['settings']))
  {
    $settings = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, ' .
      drupal_json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $javascript['settings']['data'])) .
    ');</script>';
  }

  $response['form'] = $rendered_form . $settings;
  drupal_json_output($response);
}
```

Finally, you need to make an ajax call to get your form, and append it to the page somewhere, finally calling Drupal.attachBehaviors()

```
$.ajax(
{
  url:'/my/ajax/callback',
  success:function(data)
  {
    // Create a div and set the returned data as the contents,
    // so as to turn them into HTML
    var formElement = $("<div/>").html(data.form).contents();

    // Append the form somewhere on the page
    $("#some_container").append(formElement);

    // Finally call Drupal.attachBehaviors
    Drupal.attachBehaviors(formElement);
  }
});
```

For more of an understanding on what I'm doing with Drupal behaviors, read my tutorial on working with JavaScript in Drupal 7, in particular the section on attaching behaviors: http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/high-performance-javascript-using-drupal-7s-javascript-api

Comment: Well, you beat me to it. I was going to suggest using regular links, giving them a class of 'use-ajax' and pointing them at the callback that generates the form, avoiding writing any jQuery ajax js. Instead, I had used the AJAX Command framework in the past, as part of the menu item callback response.

Comment: @Kevin I would suggest you to post your method. Your way sounds more Drupal sense.

Comment: Yeah, it never hurts to see more than one method, giving more options. But as far as 'more Drupal sense', this ties into Drupal APIs, and is entirely Drupal.

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up a concrete example. It worked well for me, but you definitely need to mind things like cache_form and such. Basically, the menu callback gets the form, renders it, writes the HTML to a modal container, appends that to the body, then calls the applicable modal open command and returns those commands in the menu callback. Drupal then fires them off, and poof, modal opens with just the form - every time the link is clicked. Since the only overhead is generating the form, it can be quite fast.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this code to work Jaypan.. Is there anything else I need apart from the top two sets of code in a custom module and the jquery added with the theme's .info? I get a 500 error when I enter the #form_id correctly and a 200 error with an incorrect #form_id.\

Comment: @Kevin, I already had similar functionality with colorbox_node and formblock putting the form on a custom panel page.. Very easy to send arguments etc. In this case, I really need this form to be loaded in the background and then I just manually change the conditional fields with jQuery. It's an LMS so end-users want fast forms.

Comment: Niall - I suggest turning this into a conversation and posting your code, or posting your code to pastebin or something so we can see what you have. It's impossible to debug without seeing more. Although, did you clear your cache after implementing hook_menu()? And did you rename the function appropriately in the Drupal hook naming convention?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Yeah I've reset the cache but not sure what else to look at. http://pastebin.com/dGS1sYFQ

Comment: I loaded this up on a new Drupal install.. It doesn't print the form fully but the page callback works. There must be some problem with my site.

Comment: Pathauto causes an error page for the page callback.. Enabling it on the new Drupal install breaks it or if I disable it on my main site, the error page goes away. If you look at my pastebin, is there anything you see that would cause that?

Comment: I don't know why pathauto would cause the problem. Maybe try changing your path? Pathauto should only act on nodes.

Your pastebin looks fine. The problem is somewhere else. When you get an error, look in your PHP and Drupal logs to find the error - that will help track down the problem